# rActivity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am trying to create a Push Notification, but getting following error.

```
Error:- 12-02 11:48:05.358: E/WindowManager(30842): Activity    
com.example.mygooglecloudemessaging.RegisterActivity has leaked window 
android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer@40eaa0a0 that was originally added here
```

Activity:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    ConnectionDetector cd;

    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtEmail;

    Button btnRegister;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {

            alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            return;
        }

        // Check if GCM configuration is set
        if (SERVER_URL == null || SENDER_ID == null || SERVER_URL.length() == 0
                || SENDER_ID.length() == 0) {
            // GCM sernder id / server url is missing
            alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this, "Configuration Error!",
                    "Please set your Server URL and GCM Sender ID", false);
             return;
        }

        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Read EditText dat
                String name = txtName.getText().toString();
                String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();

                // Check if user filled the form
                if(name.trim().length() > 0 && email.trim().length() > 0){
                    // Launch Main Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);


                    i.putExtra("name", name);
                    i.putExtra("email", email);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }else{
                    // user doen't filled that data
                    // ask him to fill the form
                    alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Error!", "Please enter your details", false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of error comes when you just keep open any layout and that never being closed.
Check all of your code somewhere you are forget to cancel the dialog before switching to another view.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change this-

```
alert.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this,
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
```

to

```
alert.showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
```

change for both the alertDialog, this is causing the memory leak. Your very issue is discussed here: [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: @Yup AlertDialog requires a Context whose window Token is not null.
here getApplicationContext() will return a Context whose window token is null. here we have to pass Activity reference as Activiy's Context window token is not null...

Comment: @AmitJayaswal - can you please tell why you have used `return` inside `if- block`, what you are looking for by return statement.